# How do I learn making modern illustrations?

Tags: illustration, education

What are some good resources to learn this type of illustration?

I would like some help to decompose the technical elements that serve as building blocks for making theses types of illustrations

[image]

source: https://dribbble.com/shots/4950216-Online-shopping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several possibilities, but some common points that may be useful for a beginner:

- Make a paper sketch of your idea ([Photo](https://unsplash.com/photos/wbu4q8xk2Kc) from unsplash.com)

[image: sketch]

- Choose a vector application: Adobe Illustrator, Corel Draw, Inskape, Sketch, Affinity Designer...
- Decompose your illustration into basic shapes

[image: shapes]

- Use guides

[image: guides]

- Make your own swatches palette

[image: palette]

- Learn vector illustration techniques following tutorials [like this one](https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-easy-living-room-scene-in-illustrator--vector-24995)

Answer (score 11):

This will be a totally obvious answer.

**The same way as old illustrations. Practice.**

We are living in an era where the information, tutorials, tips, tools are there, but somehow we hesitate a lot on **just doing it**.

The tools are the same as they have been from centuries. Perspective, concept, style, color.

The specific styles of gradients have been used in old Soviet, art deco, airbrushed posters from the 80's.

---

Make one block with the proper perspective, you have the tabletop, make another block you have the table base. Add a gradient, add another gradient.

And I do not mean you use a  specific tool. You could do it on paper, making gradients with a toothbrush or you could do that in Illustrator, Corel or whatever.

If you do not know how to make a specific step... google that specific step.

- How do I make a rectangle in X program?
- How do I skew it?
- How do I add a gradient?
- How do I add noise to the gradient?

But you need to see your own image. "What else do I need? Do I need a shadow? Where should it be?"

Take one notebook and make one drawing in one or two minutes. Practice drawing for 30 minutes. You will have 30 drawings a day. In one month you will have more than one thousand drawings.

Draw your kitchen, your couch, the paper bag of the groceries, your aunt, the dog.

Do not assume you know how the dog is, see it, "feel" the real dog.

---

This is how it has been for ages. "Modern" Illustrations are just a style.

Modern is a term used in vanguard art from the late 19th century and early 20th century, so modern is not that modern.

Comment: Tools are not like they have been for centuries but yes still relevant

Comment: I stand corrected. Some cave paintings of hands, for example, could have been made by blowing pigments masked with the hands, so some tools have been for millennia. :o)